# WebdriverIO click not working on firefox but working on chrome

Tags: selenium, ubuntu, firefox, xpath, webdriver-io

I am writing a simple webdriverIO test where I am clicking on an element. When running the test on Chrome, it works fine but for some reason, nothing happens when I run the test on Firefox. There is no error for this.

This is the element

```
<span class="cdc4f612">More Options</span>
```

I am using the following XPath to locate the element:

```
//span[text()='More Options']
```

or

```
//*[text()='More Options']

browser.click(xpath)
```

I am using the following versions:

Selenium Standalone Server: 3.7.1

Firefox: 56.0.2 (64-bit)

Geckodriver: 0.18.0

Ubuntu: 17.04

Comment: Hey Adeel! Can you also provide the error traceback? Anyways, the issues with `geckodriver` are well known, but for something as common as a `.click()` it should work nontheless.

Comment: Hi @iamdanchiv. I do not see any error on the terminal when running tests from the terminal.

Comment: Hmm... can you set your `logLevel` to `verbose` (in the `wdio.config.js` file) and re-run, then attach the error. WDIO should report errors by default though A.F.A.I.K.

Comment: @iamdanchiv  
Here is the logs for the tests. I dont see any error here. https://docs.google.com/document/d/1khn_cpTQTRrTvuPE281rgeXL4DICZp_pVieJwT4pAas/edit?usp=sharing